# How to prevent \underbrace from overlapping with a \chemfig?

Tags: spacing, braces, chemfig

A chemical formula I'm annotating overlaps with an underbrace, unless I use brackets. How can I prevent overlap without placing brackets?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
$\underbrace{\chemfig{*6(-\chembelow{N}{H}-(=O)--\chemabove{N}{H}-(=O)-)}}_{\textnormal{glycine anhydride}}$
 vs. 
$\underbrace{\left[\chemfig{*6(-\chembelow{N}{H}-(=O)--\chemabove{N}{H}-(=O)-)}\right]}_{\textnormal{glycine anhydride}}$
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the uppercase version `\Chembelow` (there's also `\Chemabove`) to extend the bounding box of the molecule:

```
$\underbrace{
  \chemfig{*6(-\Chembelow{N}{H}-(=O)--\chemabove{N}{H}-(=O)-)}
}_{\textnormal{glycine anhydride}}$
```

BTW: you can use `chemfig`'s tools and avoid mathmode completely:

```
\schemestart[-90]
  \chemup.
  \chemfig{*6(-\Chembelow{N}{H}-(=O)--\chemabove{N}{H}-(=O)-)}
  \chemdown\}
  \arrow{0}[,0]
  glycine anhydride
\schemestop
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

$\underbrace{
  \chemfig{*6(-\Chembelow{N}{H}-(=O)--\chemabove{N}{H}-(=O)-)}
}_{\textnormal{glycine anhydride}}$

\bigskip

\schemestart[-90]
  \chemup.
  \chemfig{*6(-\Chembelow{N}{H}-(=O)--\chemabove{N}{H}-(=O)-)}
  \chemdown\}
  \arrow{0}[,0]
  glycine anhydride
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the reason I'm using math mode for annotation is that it's WYSIWYG-editable in LyX.

Answer (score 1):

Here, I just `\addstackgap[10pt]{}` to the `\chemfig`, which pads the argument, top and bottom, with a buffer the size of the optional argument (default 3pt).

Alternately, it can be done without a package by adding a `\rule`.  In the MWE below, both approaches are shown.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig,stackengine}

\begin{document}
$\underbrace{\addstackgap[10pt]{\chemfig{*6(-\chembelow{N}{H}-(=O)--\chemabove{N}{H}-(=O)-)}}}_{\textnormal{glycine anhydride}}$
\quad
$\underbrace{\rule[-30pt]{0pt}{30pt}\chemfig{*6(-\chembelow{N}{H}-(=O)--\chemabove{N}{H}-(=O)-)}}_{\textnormal{glycine anhydride}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: any other idea without importing another package?

Comment: @Sparkler Please see postscript to my answer.